# converting from mysql to PDO username confirmation issue

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo

how do I convert this mysql to a PDO? I am having issues trying to get the code to verify if the username already exists.

```
//Check if user already exists

$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");

//Count the amount of rows where username = $un

$check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);



if ($check == 0) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want to do this with a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$u_check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= :username");
$u_check->execute(array(':username' => $un));
if($u_check->rowCount()) {
```

Comment: Even better to use the `PDO_PARAM_STRING`, etc constants

Comment: @self execute(array()) doesn't support those, then you'd need to resort to bindValue/bindParam, i believe

Comment: DO NOT use rowCount with a select query!! 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php
For a portable count of selected rows, use fetchAll() to fetch all rows into an array, then count() on the resulting array.

Comment: Good point @fpierrat (I've only tinkered with PDO so I missed this)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Machavity about the prepared statement:

```
$u_check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= :username");
$u_check->execute(array(':username' => $un));
```

***But for a portable count of selected rows***, you should prefer:

```
$rows=$u_check->fetchAll();
if(count($rows)) {...
```

see  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php for details on restriction in the use of `rowCount()` for select queries (portability problems, depends on underlying DB).

Comment: Even better is to use `SELECT COUNT(username) as count`, rather than fetching a whole result-set and counting it. Since he merely wants to count

Comment: In the present case it doesn't make a great difference. If I understand the question correctly, the OP wants to know if the user "already exists" (probably to create it or refuse its creation), so the "whole set" to fetch will be 0 or 1 row... and the `select count()` result will also have to be fetched (1 row) ;-)  
For general cases where you need data _and_ number of rows, you will fetch in any case. That's why I quite always proceed like this.
But you're right, if _only_ counting is needed, of course there's no need to fetch large sets of data just to have them counted.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(username) is totally useless in PDO. PDO rowCount() is the proper method

Comment: Ni, this solution doesn't work with Every DB, PHP manual expressely warns AGAINST rowcount fort select requests, see the link I posted in m'y answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always bind parameters in PDO with proper type definition to avoid PDO predictive type process. Avoid execute with array as possible as this imply predictive PDO process.

Use PDO rowCount before the fetch (faster than anything else).

```
$u_check = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?"
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($u_check);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $un, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($count>=1){
    $result= $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: As already pointed out several times here, this doesn't work with every DB and should be avoided, see PHP doc, pdostatement::rowcount section (link in my answer). Thouh I agree rowcount might be faster, I prefer reliable and portable code, so I only use functions for what they have been meant and what they are documented for :-) You sometimes need code that doesn't work _only_ with mysql, when using an abstract layer like pdo.

Comment: Though I agree OP question mentions mysql, and rowcount _seems_ to work with select queries as well -still it's not explicitly documented, even for mysql, as far as I know -but even then, I'd still prefer something portable...